# in jmeter how can I parameterize test plans on remote servers?

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I am using jmeter to run some load tests and have it set up for distributed testing. I want to run the same test plan on each remote machine but want to somehow parameterize each run based on which remote server it is running. The test plan has a single thread-group which runs through an infinite loop of test samplers. The test samplers are all selenium based test cases and open browsers to load web pages. For example when I run the load test I want something like:

```
server 1: run threadgroup with 10 users using selenium + ghost webdriver
server 2: run threadgroup with 1 user using selenium + chrome webdriver
server 3: run threadgroup with 1 user using selenium + firefox webdriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh this is a total hack and I dont like it but here is how I solved it.

1). Create 1 user defined variables (add->Config->User Defined Variables). Add the config for all hosts as a separate row like this:

- 10.1.2.1_numThreads = 10
- 10.1.2.2_numThreads = 1
- 10.1.2.3_numThreads = 2

2). In the thread group set the Number of Threads value as:

```
${__V(${__machineIP()}_numThreads)}
```

It will create 10 users if the test plan runs on 10.1.2.1, 1 user if it runs on 10.1.2.2, 2 users if it runs on 10.1.2.3. In this way I am able to parameterize each server and pass as many different variables to each server as I want just by updating the single user defined config element. You can use the __machineName() function instead of machineIP() if that is easier. In windows you can get the machine name by right clicking my computer and selecting properties - it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSV file with same file name & same path on Server 1, Server 2 & Server 3.

Keep different values in Server1, Server 2 & Server 3.

So when you provide the file name & path in the Master Jmeter machine (Controller) e.g. C:\test.csv

the load generators (remote servers) will search for this file in their local path.

Hope this will help.

Comment: How does this allow me to change the number of threads/users on the other machines? Those need to be added in the test plan as far as I know. I was thinking in the threadgroup I can use some function that checks what the current machines IP address is and chooses the number of threads based on that. IS something like the following possible: __decode(__getIpAddress(),"192.0.0.1",10,"192.0.0.2",1,"192.0.0.3",1)